# mini-css-extract plugin with postcss throws this.getOptions is not a function

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css, postcss, mini-css-extract-plugin

I'm trying to set up a tailwind css for my personal project. It's a react SSR application. I'm having an issue with postcss setup under the webpack configuration. It throws the same error on every *.css file (even on the empty ones).

It looks like it can't resolve the configuration file or default options? Tried different configurations, but no effect. Initially, I thought that it could be something with my css files, but they all valid and compile if I remove postcss plugin

**webpack config**

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');

const paths = require('./paths');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: path.resolve(paths.projectSrc, 'index.js'),
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@src': paths.projectSrc,
    },
  },
module: {
  rules: [
  {
    test: /.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: { minimize: true },
      },
    ],
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  },
  {
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        options: {
          publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, './client-build/css/'),
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: { importLoaders: 1 },
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          postcssOptions: {
            config: path.resolve(__dirname, 'postcss.config.js'),
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|otf|eot|png|jpg|svg|gif)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: './assets/[name].[ext]',
    },
  },
],
},
  plugins: [
    new ESLintPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(paths.public, 'index.html'),
      filename: 'index.html',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].bundle.css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: path.resolve(paths.public, 'assets'), to: 'assets' }],
    }),
  ],
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
};
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

**console output**

[image: webpack output]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is caused by a breaking change in ***v5.0.0*** of `postcss-loader` where support for version ***4*** of `webpack` was dropped.

---

***[README](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/postcss-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)*** which states:

## Changelog

All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file. See [standard-version](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/standard-version) for commit guidelines.

### [5.0.0](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/postcss-loader/compare/v4.2.0...v5.0.0) (2021-02-02)

#### ⚠ BREAKING CHANGES

- minimum supported `webpack` version is `5`

---

### How to fix it

You will need to downgrade `postcss-loader` to ***v4.2***.

### Side Note for Angular Projects

In case this helps other readers: You may not just see this in React projects. I found this issue after upgrading an Angular 8 project to Angular 11.

While I can't help with React projects, this Angular hint may also be of use anyways.
If you are on an Angular project and you've already tried to fix this issue by upgrading to ***v5*** of `webpack` and then ran into dependency issues with libraries using ***v4*** of `webpack` - You will want to follow these steps.

1. Downgrade `postcss-loader` to **v4.2** as mentioned above.
2. Remove `webpack` **v5** from `package.json`.
3. Delete `package.lock.json`.
4. Delete `node_modules` directory.
5. Run `npm install`.
6. Run `ng serve` or `ng build`.
7. Tell the boss you fixed it.

After this, you should be good to go with tailwindcss and Angular.

Comment: I was using `less-loader` at version 8, and my solution was similar: I had to downgrade to version 7 to be able to use with Webpack 4.